# Why am I getting a list index out of range error when traversing a list matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to iterate through a matrix list i.e (go 3 values to the right, 1 down) and seeing the above error. The expected value is being printed to the console, which would suggest the value exists and is not out of range.

```
grid = []

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line.strip()
        grid.append(line)
print(grid)

col = 2
row = 0
count = 0

for i in enumerate(grid):
    row = row + 1
    print(grid[row][col])
    if grid[row][col] == "#":
        print("found")
        print(grid[row][col])
        count = count+1
    col = col + 3
```

This problem also persists if I don't increment the row and col values.  My input data is here:

```
.........###......#...#.......#
.#.#...........#..#..#.........
#.......#.................#....
.........#.#.........#......###
.....#......##...##............
...##...#......#.....#.....##..
#.#..#....#...#....#......#....
........##.....#.....#.#.......
......#.....#......#...##.#....
...####...#.......##.....#.#...
.........#....#......##........
..##...........###.#...........
.....#............#............
#.#..#..##........#.....#..#...
.....................#....##..#
...........##.....###...#.#.#..
..#......#...........#.........
.##.##...#...#......##.#.......
......#..#......#.#.#..#.#.....
........#.#..#..........#...#.#
...........##...........#....#.
...........#...##.#............
.......#...........#...........
.......#......#..#...#....#..#.
..#.....#.#....#.#......#...#.#
.#..........###..#....#........
........##..#..#...#..#....#..#
#..........#...#..#.#........#.
..#.#........##.##....##.#.....
#.##....#...#.......#.#..#....#
......##...#.#.#.#.....#....#..
..........#..............#.....
....................###.#......
#.....#...#...#.#.......#....#.
.......#..#...................#
........##.##........#......#..
...#...##.#...#...........#....
..#.........#...#....##......#.
......#..............#..#..#.#.
.....##...#...#...##....#......
#.#....#...#......##.....#...##
.#...#.#..................#....
#.##.....#......#..........#...
..#..#.......#.................
..#.....#.........#........#...
.......#...##.##.#..#..##.#..#.
#.............#.........#.#....
..#..##..........#..#..##.#.#..
.#......#.......#...#.....##.#.
.....#......#...#...........###
..........#.........#.....#....
.....#..........#.......##...#.
......#..#..#..............#...
.#.####..#...##...#.#..........
..#....#.......#........#.....#
....#.##.....#..#.....#.#.#..#.
.......#..#..##.......#........
.#.....#...........#.....#.....
........#..........##..##.#....
.#.....#........#.....#..#.....
..#..........#...#......##..#..
.#............#.........#....#.
........#..###.......#.....###.
##.#...#.#..#..#..#.#.##...#...
.#....#...#..#......##.........
.............##.....##.........
.....##.#..###.#....#...#...#.#
#........#...#......#...#.##...
#....#......#.....###.##.#.....
.....#..#.#.##....#..##.....##.
....#...#...#..........##......
..........#......#...#.....##..
.....##....##.#.............#.#
#.........#.##.............#..#
.....#.........##.#...#.#.#....
..........#..#......#..#.....#.
....#....#....#....#.......###.
....#...#..##....#..##..#...##.
.###......#...........###......
#..................####.#....#.
#....#.#.....#.#....#..#.......
...#......#....##......#..#..#.
#.#...#.##.....#.#.......##..#.
.........##.................#..
#..##.#....#.#.............#...
....................####.#.#..#
.......#..#...#..#..#.....#...#
.....#.#.#........#....#...##..
......#..#....#......#..##.....
............#......##.#....#..#
...#..........#..#...........#.
..........#.............###....
....##.#.#......#.#..#....##..#
..#..........#........#......#.
..#...........####......##..#.#
...##......##...#..#.##........
.....#...#.....##.....###..##..
.#.##.....#....##....#.........
#....##..#.....#.#......#.#....
..#.......#...#....#...#.#.....
...........#.........#.........
..#..#....##..#....#....#.....#
.......#..#....##....#.........
#.........#...........##....##.
#........#.#...............##..
#...##.#...............#.......
#....#..#......#..#.###...##..#
..#.........#.#......#.....#..#
......#...........##........##.
.#.........#................#..
#...#...............#...#....#.
.#.#......##.........#.#.......
..........#....................
.#.....#..#...#.#.#.......#...#
..#..........#.................
.#.#.....#.#......#...#.....##.
.....#.#..##...##..#..###...#..
......#......#.#......#.##.....
#.#......#...#.......#....#....
..........#....#.#..#.....##...
#...........#.#....#.##....#.#.
#.#....#..#.........###....#...
..............#..##.......#....
.......................#.##.#..
##...............##....#..#.#..
.#.#..#.##...#.............#...
...#...........#............#..
..#......#........##....#.#.##.
.#.#..#........#....#....#....#
.#.....#.##....#.....#..#...#..
......#...#..........#..###....
..#.#.......#........#........#
.......##.####..........#......
.#.#..#......##..#.........#..#
..#...##.#.......#...#.##...#.#
#.#..........#..#.#.#..........
.....#......#............#.....
........###...#.......#........
.....#.##....#....#............
...#.#....##.....#.....#.......
..#.............#......#.......
.#....#...#....##..#......#....
..#.....#.#............#.......
......#........##.........#...#
.......#........#..#.#.#...##.#
#....#...#..#.......#....##....
#...##.#.#.....#.......#.......
.....#........#.#.....#...##...
..#....#..##......#.#.....#...#
....#.....#......#.....#.......
#.#....#......#...##...........
..#.......#...#...............#
........#........#.............
#.#.#......#...#..#..........#.
.##...#.........#........#..#..
#.#.#...#.#.......#.....#...#..
...#..............#..........#.
#.#...#.###.............#......
................#.....###.##.#.
.......#..........#....#..#....
......##....#..#..##...........
...#...#.....######.......#....
..##.....##.#...#.........#.#.#
.......#...#..#.#.#...........#
........###.............#...#.#
#.....#.........#.............#
..#...#.....#..................
.....#....#.....#......#.#....#
...#....#........##...#.......#
...##.#...#.....#..............
..#.##....##..#.........#......
.....#..#.#....#...#......#.#..
...........##..##...#..#..###..
#...........#.........####....#
.#...........#...........###...
........#................#.....
.....#....#............#....#.#
...#...#.......#...............
#.....##.#.......#.#...........
#.......#.#.#.#..#...#.........
....####.#...#.#......#.....##.
...##...#.....#.#......#..#....
..........#..#....#......###...
...................#....##...#.
....#......#........#...##..#..
##...#.........#.#......#......
#........#...#....#......#.....
#..#.......#...............##..
......##......#...........##.#.
......#..#....#....#.##........
..#....#..#.#.###....#.........
.#......#..#..............#....
.#..........#...#..#.#...#.....
....#......#..#......#....#....
...##.....#............####..#.
......#.#...#....#..#...#..#.#.
......##.......................
#.##........#...........####..#
.....#......#.......#.#....#...
#.......#....#.....#....#...##.
.....#..##.#...........#..#...#
...........#.##.#.#...#.#..#...
..#.......#.#....#..#..........
...#.......##..#.............#.
....#..#....#....#...#....#....
#......#.#...##..........#..#..
..#.#.......#.........#......#.
#...............#.............#
....##..#......................
.##....#............#......#...
.......#....#..##......##......
#..##.....#..#..........#......
...#.........#.......#..##.....
....#.##.....#.#...#...#.....#.
##...........#.#..#...#.#......
....#.............##...#.#..#..
...#....#......................
#..#...##.#.......#.##..#.###..
...##.#.#...##........##...#...
......##..#..#.....#..#.#..#...
#.......##...............##.#..
.##......#..#....#...##..#..#.#
##.........##..#...#.....##....
...#..........#...#..##.#......
..##.#........#...#..........##
.......................##.#....
....#...#...#..###.#.......#.##
....#....#.#..........#.##.....
..#..........##...#....#.......
.....#.....#.....#..#.........#
..##..##..#..#....#..#.......##
.............#............##...
....#.#.#.......###.........#..
...##.#..........#.#...#.#.....
.#........#..#.#.#..#..........
...##...#.....##.......#..#..#.
...#......#..#.......##.#.#....
.........#.........##........#.
.........##..................##
....##.....#................#..
....#..................##...#.#
.........#..............#......
...#......#..#..#....#..#...##.
.#.##......##...#.#......#.#...
...#.#...###....#...#.#..#....#
....#..#.......#.....#..##.#.#.
#.#.#..#.......#####.#..##..#..
#..........#.....#..#.#..#.....
.#......#...#..#.#..#..#.......
...#....##...#..........#.##.#.
#.##..#...#..................#.
......#.###..#..#..#.......#...
...#....#...#..#............###
#.........#........#.......#...
...#..#.................#....##
...#.#.............##......#...
##....#.##.............##......
#............#..#..#.....#.....
....#........#...#.....#.#...##
..#.##..#.....................#
#.#........#...#..#...#.#......
...#..#...........##.....#.....
......#.#....#..##...#.....#...
......#......#.###..##.........
....#.......#...##.##.....#....
#.....##....#........#..##.....
.#..#..#..#..#.#...#...#.......
.......##...#......#.........#.
.#..##....#.....#...........##.
.......##....#.#........#......
..#.#.#....#...................
.#...#.......#...#.#......#....
..##.##..##...........###......
#...#......#.......#...........
#....##.#.......#.........#....
.............##.#.#..#...#...#.
..##.##...........#.........##.
#.#...#..........#.#....#....##
.....#.....#..##..#............
#.........#.........#.#...##..#
...#.#.....#.........###..#....
..#.#.##.#...................#.
......####....#.......#.......#
.........#..#..#....#..##......
....#..........#...##........#.
..........#..#....#.....#....#.
.#.#.................#....#....
.......#......#.....#...##.....
....#..............#...........
###...........##.#...........#.
...####.......#...#....#.#...#.
..##.#................#........
...#..#....#.....#.....##..#...
##.#....#....##..........#.#..#
...#....#.....#................
..#...#....#..#..#.##.##..#....
....#....#.##.....#...#......#.
......#................#..#..#.
...##..#...#....#.#.....#..#...
#...#..............#.#.....#.#.
....#.........#.##...#.#....#..
..................#..##.#......
.#.....#.....#.............#..#
..........####....###..##...#..
......#........#...#......##..#
#......#.#..........#....#.#...
###................#.#....#....
#..#.##.#.............#..#.....
.....#............#.....##.....
....#.....#....#.........#.....
#..#...........###.#....#......
..#............##...#........##
..#....#..#....#.....#.......#.
..#..#.#.#.##.#..#...#.....#...
..........#..#.................
...#.#......#..##........#.....
...............#...............
#.......#.......#....#.........
#...........#....#.............
....#..#..........#....#..##...
.........#.#.#.........#......#
.....#...##.....#.#.......#...#
.........#....#...#.......#....
```

Comment: If your problem persists if you don't increment row and col values, it most likely means that you have less than three columns in your grid. Are you reading your data correctly? (if you post a minimal reproducible example, it would certainly help since we can't see your data which makes debugging a little difficult)

Comment: Also you are iterating through both rows and collumns at once which is kind of confusing. You probably don't want to do that. (Unless you really do, in which case I am sorry for being smartypants.)

Comment: Yep. Now I'm sure. your code will fail at 11th iteration of the loop as it will try to access 32th column. Unfortunately you only have 31 of them, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

**Python lists(and matrices) are zero indexed.**

You are adding 1 to the row too early, so in the last row you instead try to access the nonexistent row after the last one. Try placing the `row = row + 1` just before the `col = col + 1`. Then proceed to debug from there.

Alternatively you could start with `row = -1`, which should work however it is kind of 'dirty'.

Also since you are already using enumerate, you might want to consider

```
for idx, i in enumerate(grid):
    grid[idx][col] == '#'
```

since enumerate already gives you the indices you need.

Comment: Your solution works for a small dataset however I am seeing the same error when trying with a larger dataset. I have tried both setting the value to -1 and also relocating the increment statement.

Also, I need to increment manually the row and column and not traverse in a linear fashion - can I do this with the  suggestion you posted?

Comment: In that case there is the other part I just posted in your comments - you are iterating through both rows and columns at once, which will work only in case that you have at least 3 times as many columns as the current row index. And that is something I wouldn't bet on. You probably want second loop inside, that would iterate over columns. Or some other kind of logic behind that. Not blindly increasing col index by three in every row.